# Getting session id

Tags: python

So my goal is to simply get session id from the running the code below.

```
def get_sid():
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    ws.connect("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=9&encoding=json")
    hello = json.loads(ws.recv())
    print(hello)
    auth = {
        "op": 2,
        "d": {
            "token": token,
            "properties": {
                "$os": "windows",
            },
        }
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(auth))
    res = json.loads(ws.recv())
    return res
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: @g14u websocket, json

Comment: @wuhoyt tried saving the whole response then returning the session id but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had your question too;
so I do the research myself and this is result:

The main response is in the `"d"` it contains : user, session, guild and so much more informations
so you must do:

```
response = get_sid()
sessionid = response["d"]["session_id"]
```

I hope this help you